# In Bash in a macOS environment, how can extract a sentence before a word and after a word in an XML document?

Tags: bash, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get just the text "Passwords do not match" between `<Description>` and `</Description>` from the variable $webout using regex. I'm brand new to regex, so please explain in detail the solution and how to format it within the bash script so I can learn.

Text from $webout Variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><interface-response><Command>SETDNSHOST</Command><Language>eng</Language><ErrCount>1</ErrCount><errors><Err1>Passwords do not match</Err1></errors><ResponseCount>1</ResponseCount><responses><response><Description>Passwords do not match</Description><ResponseNumber>304156</ResponseNumber><ResponseString>Validation error; invalid ; password</ResponseString></response></responses><Done>true</Done><debug><![CDATA[]]></debug></interface-response>
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=ifconfig.me
pip=$(curl -s ${url})
upip="https://dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/update?host=[hostname]&domain=[domain.com]&password=[password]&ip=${pip}"
webout=$(curl -s $upip)
echo $webout(<Description>(.*?)<)
#echo $(date +'%D %H:%M') $pip >> /users/username/documents/itworks.txt
```

The problems i've ran into I believe is caused by the "/" in `</Description>`. That and i'm having a very difficult time grasping regex formatting.

Thank you

Comment: It's recommended to parse XML with an XML parser. [tag:xmlstarlet] is a good one for scripts. You can install it with Homebrew on the Mac.

Comment: @glennjackman there is. The sentence "Passwords do not match" appears twice :)

Comment: May I suggest that you first paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and get it syntactically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two bash examples:

```
webout='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><interface-response><Command>SETDNSHOST</Command><Language>eng</Language><ErrCount>1</ErrCount><errors><Err1>Passwords do not match</Err1></errors><ResponseCount>1</ResponseCount><responses><response><Description>Passwords do not match</Description><ResponseNumber>304156</ResponseNumber><ResponseString>Validation error; invalid ; password</ResponseString></response></responses><Done>true</Done><debug><![CDATA[]]></debug></interface-response>'


sed -n  "s:.*<Description>\(.*\)</Description>.*:\1:p" <<< $webout


grep -oP '(?<=<Description>).*(?=</Description>)' <<< $webout
```

To be honest, the second command (`grep`) is using a syntax that I'm not too familiar with (I just picked it up here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match ).

However, when you are parsing XML, you are better off not using regex but rather an xml parser.

Here's a third option using an XML parse (xmllint):

```
xmllint --xpath '//Description/text()' -  <<< $webout
```

Note:  I had to change utf-16 to utf-8 to make xmllint happy.

After I read comments and other answers, on this page, I discovered that iconv is the command for converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16.  Here's an improved version:

```
xmllint --xpath '//Description/text()' <(  iconv -f utf-8  -t utf-16 <<< $webout )
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark. The sed solution works. I'd like to take your advice and use an XML parser, but i'm running into errors trying pass $webout through iconv first. Any suggestions?

`./ddns.sh: command substitution: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token ``('
./ddns.sh: command substitution: line 8: ``xmllint --xpath '//Description/text()' - <<<(iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 $webroot)'`

Comment: Hi @Tazarok - use <(iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 $webroot)  - the <<< is incorrect.

Comment: @Tazarok - I updated my answer with how to include <().  The <() command runs a subshell and returns a temporary file name that can be read by the input program.  In this case, we are telling xmllint to read the temp file (or named pipe) <() instead of reading from stdin (the dash '-').

Comment: That works as well! I really appreciate your help/replies! I now have code to learn from and can see it actually work! Have a great night.

Answer (score 6):

With [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```bash
# this is a placeholder for your curl call
webout='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><interface-response><Command>SETDNSHOST</Command><Language>eng</Language><ErrCount>1</ErrCount><errors><Err1>Passwords do not match</Err1></errors><ResponseCount>1</ResponseCount><responses><response><Description>Passwords do not match</Description><ResponseNumber>304156</ResponseNumber><ResponseString>Validation error; invalid ; password</ResponseString></response></responses><Done>true</Done><debug><![CDATA[]]></debug></interface-response>'

desc=$(
    echo "$webout" \
    | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 \
    | xmlstarlet sel -t -v //Description
)

declare -p desc
```

outputs

```
declare -- desc="Passwords do not match"
```

`iconv` was needed to avoid "Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content" error (from copy-pasting your sample data, YMMV)

Comment: Have never used `iconv`, but with that knowledge, `xmllint` might be another option: `desc=$(xmllint --xpath '//Description/text()' - < <(iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 x.xml))`